# Java script to update the input field of an object on VF page based on select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, visualforce

I created a VF page with input fields of Account Object. I created a select list on Vf page using controller. I want to update the input field(selected__c : datatype--text) with same value selected option in select list.

I tried below code but it is not updating the selected value to the input field.
Can anyone help me with this .

```
`<apex:pageblocksection>

<apex:selectList value="{!selectedVal}" multiselect="false" readonly="true"  onchange="updateField()" size="1" id="ddlViewBy">
<apex:selectOptions id="selectid" value="{!contact}"/>
</apex:selectList>
<apex:inputfield id="customfield" value="{!Account.Match__c}"></apex:inputfield>

 </apex:pageblocksection>
<script>
 function updateField() {
 var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
 var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
 document.getElementById("customfield") = strUser;

 }

 </script>`
```

Controller :

```
public List<SelectOption> getcontact() {   
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
     Account a = [Select id,Name,OwnerId,Match__C FROM Account where id =: this.account.id]; 
   con  = [Select id, Name from Contact  where OwnerId =: a.OwnerId];
    if (con.Size() >0)
 {     
    for(Contact c : con){
    if (c.Name != null)
      options.add(new SelectOption(c.Name,c.Name));
     }
   }
   return options;
}
```

Comment: please be more specific regarding "not working".  is you function being triggered with the change of the select?  are you able to get the value of the selected option?  are you able to assign that value to "customfield" ?

Comment: It is not updating input field.

Comment: so you've verified that strUser has the value you expect to see ?

Comment: Check http://salesforceworld.blogspot.com.by/2011/06/javascript-with-visualforce-pages.html and http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/select-all-checkbox-using-javascript-in-visualforce-page/ to learn, how to use Javascript on Visualforce page.